# Is it possible to tell Composer not to uninstall already installed dependencies when using the composer command?

Tags: php, composer-php

I am using https://github.com/tonix-tuft/grunt-hub-automator (a repo I have created on GitHub) which lets me set up a daemon which runs the following command whenever I change my `composer.json` or `composer.lock` file:

```
composer self-update && composer install --no-dev && composer update --lock
```

This way I can move across different branches and the daemon keeps the dependencies in `vendor` synchronized with `composer.json`.

However, if after adding new dependencies on **new_branch** I checkout **old_branch** which doesn't have those dependencies defined in `composer.json` because I have added them only on **new_branch**, the daemon fires the command and removes the dependencies on the old branch to keep everything in sync.

The problem of this approach is that if at that point I checkout again **new_branch** before the `composer` command has finished its work on **old_branch** (it's running in the background thanks to the daemon), I end up with an unsynced `vendor` folder because Composer is removing the dependencies as it thinks I am still on `old_branch`.

Is there a way to tell Composer not to remove already installed dependencies from `vendor` when they are not defined in `composer.json`?

Basically, I would like Composer to install missing dependencies or update those which are defined in `composer.json` every time `composer.json` changes **without removing eventual dependencies** which were already installed in vendor but now are not defined in `composer.json` anymore.

Is it possible?

I hope I was clear.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: What if old_branch needs DepA version 1 and the new_branch needs DepA version 2? It won't be possible to reconcile the two.

Comment: @apokryfos In this case, it should update the dependency... I just want them not to be removed.

Comment: Yes but you'll still end up with the inconsistent state if you checkout again before the composer command finishes. You'll end up with the wrong DepA version for the exact same reason and this is impossible to resolve automatically.

Comment: That won't be much a problem, the packages I use are not updated so often, it's their constant removal which annoys me a bit.

Comment: Unfortunately for composer as a whole this would be a problem, hence why it removes the old files. I don't think there is a way around this other than making sure you run composer install again after switching branches,